# Unattended upgrades behind proxy

Tags: apt, upgrade, proxy

We're are behind a corporate proxy and like to check for updates via the unattended upgrades mechanism. However, despite adding the necessary proxy settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf*`, `/etc/environment` and even `/etc/wgetrc`, I can see the processes "hang" forever, i.e. the `apt-get update` process never finishes, apparently trying to establish a connection to the internet. It locks `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and I have to kill the process.

Where do I make the necessary proxy settings?

PS: `apt-get update` on the console while logged in works flawlessly.

Comment: I'm not sure apt can work via proxy.

Comment: Well, I'm sure because it works while logged in. I suspect I have to make certain modifications to `apt-daily.service` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` but don't know which ones.